# session.setAttribute() No effect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a RESTful, api for importing data, which takes a long time to import.  I have another api that can query the status of the current import from the session.  But it did not set RUNNING successfully, I can only see the state of FINISH until import is finished.

With my limited experience with java, I don't know why.
How to improve it? Thanks in advance.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "deltaImport", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
httpSession.setAttribute("IMPORT_STATUS", "RUNNING");
solrService.deltaImport(startPosition, maxResult);//take a long time..
httpSession.setAttribute("IMPORT_STATUS", "FINISH");

@RequestMapping(value = "query_Status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
httpSession.getAttribute("IMPORT_STATUS")//print null or FINISH without RUNNING
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there a spec as to when attributes are "flushed"? Also, if this is a multi-node setup, the session would need to be shared between nodes.

Comment: Can you confirm that the two concurrent calls are both utilizing the same session? Is there a chance that the default value of IMPORT_STATUS for a session happens to be "FINISH"?

Comment: [SessionId]import-->1aq53h6g4dn4l162raukxbv05o
queryStatus-->170tknqbp3jdasg9ue41dnk0h//print null 
queryStatus-->1aq53h6g4dn4l162raukxbv05o //print finish

Comment: It seems that the request does not end the session and cannot be set correctly ? (Stand-alone project without clusters.)